# How do I check if a Result is Ok or Err in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to see if a string is a valid integer using `String.toInt strVar`, but I can't figure out how to translate the `Result` to a `Bool`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pattern match the `Result`.

If you want to get Bool as an output, then for example:

```
isIntParsable str =
  case String.toInt str of
    Ok _ -> True
    _ -> False
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this question. I use Elm 0.19 and things have changed a bit. Here the new code:

```
isIntParsable str =
  case String.toInt str of
    Just _ -> True
    Nothing -> False
```

Currently `String.toInt` returns a `Maybe Int`.